# What is the proper way to use multiple heavy same VueJS components on a page?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to create custom input as VueJS component. It will have `<input type="text">` field and button. This component must implement such behavior: you can type text with autocomplete or press button which opens modal dialog with records from database and then select one. Something like this:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" @click="openModal">Choose</button>
    </span>
</div>
```

The modal dialog will contain complicated logic and a lot of HTML code. I think I will put modal dialog in other component.

After all my custom input component will be used on page in table rows like:

```
<tr v-for="item in items">
    <td><input-component :item="item"><input-component></td>
</tr>
```

The table may contain 10-30 rows and that is a question - should I exclude heavy modal dialog code from my custom input component or it is fine in VueJS to have such many tens duplications in DOM?

What variant should I choose:

1) exclude modal dialog, place it once in top of page and call it from custom input components

```
<body>
    <modal-component></modal-component>
    <table><tbody>
        <tr v-for="item in items">
            <td><input-component :item="item"><input-component></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
</body>
```

2) include modal dialog and have tens of its duplicated code in DOM

```
<body>
    <table><tbody>
        <tr v-for="item in items">
            <td><input-component :item="item"><input-component></td><!--now contains <modal-component></modal-component>-->
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [dynamic component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components) and bind the component type to a reactive property.

```js
Vue.component('customer-dialog', {
    template: '<p>Customer Dialog</p>'
})

Vue.component('supplier-dialog', {
    template: '<p>Supplier Dialog</p>'
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    dialog: null // initial dialog to use
  },
  methods: {
    showDialog: function(d) {
        this.dialog = d
        // additional dialog initialization code
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <component :is="dialog"></component>
  <button @click="showDialog('customer-dialog')">Customers</button>
  <button @click="showDialog('supplier-dialog')">Suppliers</button>
</div>
```

If you want to keep the switched-out dialogs in memory so that you can preserve their state or avoid re-rendering, you can wrap the dynamic component in a  element.

```
<keep-alive><component :is="dialog"></component></keep-alive>
```

Comment: For what of two variants do you advise to use dynamic components? Or did you mean some other, third implementation of my case?

Comment: I thought a while on your suggestion and it seems to me it is the most appropriate way to implement multiple components with modal components within.

Answer (score 0):

Just use one modal dialog for the whole page.

Fill in the dialog with relevant data from an array that will look like this

```
var dialogs = [
  { name: 'john', surname: 'snow' },
  { name: undefined, surname: undefined },
  ...
]

var currentDialog = 4
var dialogData = dialogs[currentDialog]
```

Comment: Don't you think that putting some code out of component when this component's work completely depends on this code - is a bad idea/practice? I am aware about such things as: forgetting to include modal on page with my custom input component and other human factors.

Comment: Just create a wrapper component that includes the two

Comment: I don't see how to apply wrapper component in variant with one modal and multiple custom input components.

Comment: Basically you take a modal and a table and you put them together in one component `modal-table` then you cannot forget the modal because is together with the table. If you need custom inputs you can configure them through a prop

Comment: Yes, it can work. Only my page has more code in table except custom inputs and much more code between top and table. I can use slots for this of course but my app has many such pages with different content and code, and this approach seems a little complicated for me. But your suggestion worth to think on it, truly.